# How do I give accessibility permission to my AppleScript and System Events in Mavericks?

Tags: applescript, macos, permission

I've got this old AppleScript that uses a mouseclick function:

```
activate application "Safari"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
        click at {424, 699}
    end tell
end tell
```

It no longer works, probably due to a change in how the [accessibility permissions works in Mavericks](http://www.tekrevue.com/2013/06/25/how-to-enable-access-for-assistive-devices-in-os-x-mavericks/). You need to give permissions on an app by app basis. Unfortunately, SystemEvents.app is not in the list of apps to give permissions. How can I make it appear? Is there another solution that does not depend on downloading utilities from third-parties?

This is the error message I get:

```
error "System Events got an error: Can’t make {424, 699} into type list." number -1700 from {424, 699} to list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is independent of the accessibility permission.

Replace your click line with something like `click window 1` and it will ask you to allow or deny access to the accessibility features.

There is a problem with `click at` and I don't know what it is.

Edit : My conclusion after some tests : `click at` is broken. 
The [release note of AppleScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AppleScript/RN-AppleScript/RN-AppleScript.pdf) updated with the release of Mavericks does not state some kind of removal of this feature. Some that might be a bug.

I submitted a bug report to Apple.

Edit : The issue has been fixed on Yosemite, `click at` works well again !

Comment: I did not get that result, when I ran a command containing "click window 1". Could you show me how you inserted "click window 1" into an applescript command? And I need to click a specific place in the window, how do I add location to click window 1? (If that's possible.)

Comment: `activate application "Safari"
set coor to {200, 200}
tell application "System Events"
 tell process "Safari"
  click window 1
 end tell
end tell` try also running it from terminal with `osascript`

Comment: Thanks for posting the bug! I suspect you might be right about it being a bug as I used a script with that action (literally) thousands of times. :)